# how do I implement GameCenter Leaderboard?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I haven't been able to follow other tutorials and answers on Stack Overflow, so how do I implement GameCenter Leaderboards in my game, in SpriteKit in Swift? What is the code that one would use, and would it go in the GameScene or the GameViewController? I have already set up a leaderboard on iTunes Connect. How would I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you must authenticate the player:

```
 var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if ((viewController) != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{

            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }
```

Then you can open the leaderboard:

```
 func showLeaderboard() {


        var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

        gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards


        gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "YOUR_BOARD_NAME"

        self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcViewController, animated: true)

    }
    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
    {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I suggest doing these in your view controller. Authenticate the player on viewDidAppear though not viewDidLoad

Comment: What do I have to import?

Comment: GameKit. I would suggest you actually do some research before asking questions though. Apple documents all of this information: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/index.html EDIT: You are not going to learn anything if you are spoonfed code. Try to check out the documentation to actually learn.

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses! I am receiving an error that the user is not signed in, even though I'm running this on an IOS device and I am signed into GameCenter.

Comment: You need to use a sandbox account. You can't use a regular Game Center account.

Comment: Why viewDidAppear and not viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Crashalot looking back I don't see why viewDidLoad wouldn't work because you should want it to run once when the view first loads. However, running it in viewDidAppear shouldn't cause any issues. Give it a try and let me know what happens. All I can think of is if the viewDidLoad causes a graphics error opening a new controller because the view controller is not visible and doesn't appear yet. Give a try though.